What are the games referenced in the banner for the Hooded Horse publisher sale of 2024?
One thing I absolutely hate about themed Steam sales is when their organizers make this absolutely enticing banner with appealing characters that could lead you to a game you'd buy, and then they don't tell you which games they're from.
For instance, look at the banner of the Hooded Horse publisher sale, that features Cataclismo prominently, but you wouldn't know that unless you played it already:

So I think somebody should fix that—and I suppose that's us.
Obvious references:

A starship.
Someone in sci-fi armor.
Soldier in a near-future armor.
A tiny posh king.
A big armored king.
A ginger woman in a fancy white top and a green beaked mouth mask.
An alien, a demon, or both, black with glowing yellow-orange bits, with energy swords (?) for hands.
A Roman legionnaire.
Mice dressed in Slavic headscarves (a) carrying some sort of aristocratic fat cat totem (b), which may or may not be from the same game.

Dubious references:
d-A. A medieval landscape faintly reminiscent of Toruń.
d-B. A tin toy soldier.
d-C. A white-and-red tram and bus.

It seems there's an issue with image hosting. I've made a meta post about that: Is image upload broken right now?

Obvious references:

Nebulous: Fleet Command (there's a different, but similarly-painted ship on the cover)
Menace (armor on the cover)
Xenonauts 2 (soldier on the cover)
Norland (king, as seen on the thumbnail of the second trailer on the game's store page, has a crown with a single ruby, fancy collar, and white gloves)
Super Fantasy Kingdom (king on the cover)
Cataclismo (I played the game; she is very hard to spot on the cover, since she's tiny and shown from another angle)
???
???, possibly Old World (cover features a mix of assorted historical warriors, two of which look similar to, but not quite like, Roman legionnaires)
Both from Whiskerwood (cover features mice without headscarves and the cat, but both from a different angles)

Dubious references:
d-A. Manor Lords (exact townscape on the cover)
d-B. ???
d-C. Workers & Resources: Soviet Republic (there's no bus the cover features a white-and-red train and tram, even though the tram has a flatter fron than the one on the banner)

4 is Norland. It's also not easy to spot, but during gameplay the king looks the same (e.g. the singly ruby in his crown).

A couple of these could be Terra Invicta, not sure, I got bored of that game quickly. d-C is almost certainly Workers & Resources.
